# How do I select the platform?

Tags: fifa-ultimate-team

With the release of FIFA 14, I'll return to the PS3 and leave the PC version behind. As an active FIFA 13 player I gained access to the FUT14 PC Web App. I've made some good trades and got a couple of decent players.

Tomorrow I'll start playing UT on PS3 and I'm asking myself if there is any option to select a platform (PC or PS3) in EA's web application. Somebody told me that the web app automatically redirects to the last active platform - so, as I don't have a PC version of FIFA 14, I'll lose access to my PC squad. Can somebody confirm this? If I really will lose access without the game, I'd better give away my team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To switch your profile I found this in the [FUT FAQ](https://help.ea.com/article/fifa-ultimate-team-14-faq):

> **I have more than one FUT 14 Persona. How can I switch it?**
>
> In both the web and mobiles apps you can easily switch your persona.
>
> On the Web App clicking on persona icon (represented by a person) in the lower right of the app will allow you to change your persona.
>
> In the mobile Companion App when you first sign in you will have the option to select a persona. After that you can switch it from 'Persona Selector' located in the 'More' menu.

As far as I know you are not able to play against PC-Players. So your Team will be worthless when you switch the plattform. In addition you can't share the coins.

Comment: I can confirm that switching the persona is possible. The FAQ section is totally right. However, my accounts do not share coins / FIFA points / cards / etc.

Answer (score 0):

Access to FUT 13 via the web- and mobile-applications has been disabled, in favour of FUT 14.

If you go into the game itself, you'll still be able to play matches and makes trades with you FUT 13 team on PC.

When you sign in after linking a PS3 account to your EA account, that team should be accessible to you.

Comment: Yes, FUT13 web app has been disabled. But I'm worried about my FUT14 PC team. So I'll have one EA account with FUT14 teams on PS3 and PC, but I only hold a PS3 copy of FIFA14.

Answer (score 0):

Download the mobile app, and then select the PC Persona, and then when you log in to the web app again it redirects it to the PC Account. when you need to log in back to the ps3 account, change to ps3 persona on the mobile.